# How to use a loadable bundle from a static library?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4, static-libraries, bundle

I've created a static library "**MyLib.a**" with its loadable bundle "**MyLibBundle.bundle**" which contains all needed resources such as my **xcdatamodel** and **xibs**.

Now, I want to use that library in another project.

So, I included the "**MyLib.xcodeproject**" in the new one, linked the library and specified the headers search path.

But, after all, the application can't find my core data file (**SIGABRT**).

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: The best advice I can give is to just manually copy the bundle with all of your resources, but then add the project as a build dependency in terms of the source code (which bensarz outlines). You can't include a second top-level bundle in an iOS app.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem.
Here's the best way we have found so far:

1. drag you lib.xcodeproject in your project
2. build the lib from your project using the correct scheme
3. expand the tree structure until you see the product produced by the build
4. right-click, select 'show in finder' it should end up being in ../DerivedData/Projec-HASH/Build/Products/etc...
5. drag the .bundle in your project source
6. set it to relative to build products (right pane)

Now, in your main scheme, add the bundle as a target to build before your app itself.
Also, uncheck parallelize checkbox and make sure the bundle is above the app.  This ensure your bundle gets built first, then your app will build.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this is you have to do it every time you build a new version of the lib.

Comment: What do you mean by building a new version of the lib?  If you are working on lib classes, this process will rebuild your bundle and your project will see the changes.

Comment: Oh yeah!  That took us a while to figure out! ;)  Don't forget to add it to the scheme, otherwise you have to manually rebuild the lib before building the app.

Comment: If you have found my answer useful, please consider accepting it officially.  Thanks!